# Функция должна выводить числа из диапазона и преобразовывать их в строку, но при передаче в аргумент (2, 2) выводит пустую строку вместо "2"

Tags: javascript

```
const joinNumbersFromRange = (start, finish) => {
  let i = start;
  let result = '';
  while (i < finish) {
    console.log(i);
    i += 1;
    result += i.toString();
  }
  return result;
```

Comment: Из-за условия `i < finish` вы туда не попадаете. + как то ваш код не похож на возврат "числа из дипазона". Покажите несколько примеров входных и ожидаемых выходных данных. Например, если ввести 1,3 что должно быть на выходе?

Comment: должно быть '123' выдает 12'23'. Ссылка на replit (не знаю можно так делать или нет, я еще со всем на ВЫ) https://replit.com/@ViVaLaFlame/GrimUnrealisticCryptocurrency#index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет проверки на передаваемые значения и условия цикла подразумевают, что первый аргумент строго меньше второго.

```js
function joinNumbersFromRange(start, finish) {
  if (start > finish) return '';
  if (start === finish) return start.toString();
  let result = '';
  for (let i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
    result += i;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(joinNumbersFromRange(1, 3));
console.log(joinNumbersFromRange(3, 1));
console.log(joinNumbersFromRange(2, 2));
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь дошло

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
const joinNumbersFromRange = (a, b) => {
let result = '';
let i = a;

while(i <= b) {
    result = result + i;
    i = i + 1;
}
    return result;
};
```